# Java: FilterInputStream what are the advantages and use compared to other streams

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I’ve been reading on *InputStream*, *FileInputStream*, *ByteArrayInputStream* and how their use seems quite clear (output streams too).

What I’m struggling is to understand the use of **FilterInputStream & FilterOutputStream**:

- What is the advantage of using it compared to the other stream classes?
- When should I use it?
- Please provide a theoretical explanation and a basic example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`FilterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) is an example of the [the Decorator pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

This class must be extended, since its constructor is `protected`. The derived class would add additional capabilities, but still expose the basic interface of an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

For example, a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) provides buffering of an underlying input stream to make reading data faster, and a [`DigestInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html) computes a cryptographic hash of data as it's consumed.

You would use this to add functionality to existing code that depends on the `InputStream` or `OutputStream` API. For example, suppose that you use some library that saves data to an `OutputStream`. The data are growing too large, so you want to add compression. Instead of modifying the data persistence library, you can modify your application so that it "decorates" the stream that it currently creates with a [`ZipOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html). The library will use the stream just as it used the old version that lacked compression.

Comment: OK, but BufferedInputStream and DigestInputStream actually do something with the underlying stream. What does FilterInputStream do?

Comment: It doesn't.  It's basically an invitation to extend a subclass and override the read and write functions to add whatever new functionality you might need.  Current subclasses which do this are:  BufferedInputStream, CheckedInputStream, CipherInputStream, DataInputStream, DeflaterInputStream, DigestInputStream, InflaterInputStream, LineNumberInputStream, ProgressMonitorInputStream, PushbackInputStream.

Answer (score 4):

You use them when you want to decorate the stream of data.

Remember that these stream class instances wrap themselves around another stream instance (whether another subclass of one of these or not) and add some feature, add some processing, make some changes to the data as it passes through.

For example, you might want to remove all the multiple spaces from some stream. You make your own subclass of FilterInputStream and override the `read()` method. I'm not going to bother all the details but here's some sorta-java for the method in the subclass:

```
private boolean lastWasBlank = false;
public int read() {
    int chr = super.read();
    if (chr == ' ') {
        if (lastWasBlank) {
            return read();
        } else {
            lastWasBlank = true;
        }
    } else {
        lastWasBlank = false;
    }
    return chr;
}
```

In real life, you would probably mess with the other two `read()` methods too.

Other uses:

- Log everything flowing through the stream
- Duplicate the 'tee' utility so the stream being read is handled two ways.
- Convert line endings between Windows, Mac and Unix/Linux formats
- Add delays to simulate slow transmission methods like modems or serial ports or wireless network connections.

Comment: FilterInputStream doesn't do anything to help implement a stream that filters data and correctly supports `mark`, `available`, etc. Do you know of a base class that would actually help implement an inputstream decorator?

Answer (score 2):

[FilterInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) and [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) are there to ease the job of developers who wish to implement their own input/output streams. Implementations such as [BufferedInputStream](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/BufferedInputStream-source.html) may add their own decorations around the basic `InputStream` API while delegating on the `super` class - FilteredInputStream in this case - the methods they don't need to override.

Neither `FilterInputStream` nor `FilterOutputStream` are designed for end users to use directly.